# Adding Values In a Stochastic Simulation using R

Tags: r

Here I've managed to extract extract time in discrete form such as 1,2,3...,50 from each simulation with help of the users. But, since there is no value for interval 20-21 and more, is there any coding such that I can add the value inside myself? Because, if there is no reading for that time interval, that means the readings are same until the next interval. The coding I used as below:

```
library(GillespieSSA) 
parms <- c(beta=0.591,sigma=1/8,gamma=1/7) 
x0 <- c(S=50,E=0,I=1,R=0) 
a <- c("beta*S*I","sigma*E","gamma*I") 
nu <- matrix(c(-1,0,0, 1,-1,0, 0,1,-1, 0,0,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE) 
set.seed(12345) 
out <- lapply(X=1:1,FUN=function(x) 
ssa(x0,a,nu,parms,tf=50)$data) 
out a<-as.data.frame(out) 
idx <- diff(ceiling(a$V1)) == 1 a[idx,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## change ==1 to >0
idx <- diff(ceiling(a$V1)) > 0 

## get discrete time series
discrete.data <- a[idx,]

## get the last time step value
end.time <- ceiling(tail(discrete.data$V1,1))

## create an empty data frame with all time steps
new.df <- data.frame(t=0:end.time, S=0, E=0, I=0, R=0)

## replace only those time steps that have valid values
new.df[new.df$t %in% ceiling(discrete.data$V1),2:5] <- discrete.data[,2:5]
```

If necessary missing values can be replace by `NA`, depends on how you want to handle them.